# Adding P or L (portrait or landscape) attribute for image in Magento 1.4.x

Tags: product-images, product-view, magento-1.4

I would like to add a product attribute called `orientation` to the `eav_attribute` table, and add this attribute upon upload of a product image or a category image (not necessary for others but perhaps I can do that as well).  *I want to be able to pull this information via data vs. waiting till I have the image to analyze the information*.

I have two questions:

First - what is the best approach to this?  I have searched quite a bit but because of noise on terms like iOS and etc., I haven't found anything.  I am fairly new and want to do this "the Magento way".

Second - how would I **read** this attribute in my list.phtml file?

Answer (score 1):

For products, this will not work as an EAV attribute because it won't be an attribute for the product itself, but for each image. Images are own entities, but do not use the EAV model.

So you need to do this:

- add a column `orientation` to the table `catalog_product_entity_gallery`
- modify the gallery form

Categories on the other hand just have one image and do not use the gallery tables, so you can create the attribute as usual.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a complete solution for you

Comment: ,it is not complete sol.Kindly add a note with answer